# get values of two drop down

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i was just wondering if i could get the values of two different drop downs then pass it on jquery to back to php?

you see i have these two drop downs. one for the month and one for the year.the user could choose which month and year she/he would like then the display on the graph would change depending on the month and year chosen.i was able to do it for a single drop down but i can't do it on two drop downs.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function()
   {
     $("#months").change(function(event)
    {
         var m=$(this).val();
         if( m == '00')
         { 
         }
         else if(m!='00' || m!='NULL')
         {
            $("#display").load('../crd_reports/month.php', {"m":m});
         }

    });

    $("#years").change(function(event)
    {
         var y=$(this).val();
         if( y == '10')
         {
         }
         else if(y!='10' || y!='NULL')
         {
            $("#display").load('../crd_reports/month.php', {"y":y});
         }
    });
  });
    </script>   

    <div>
  <select id="months">
    <option value='00'>Month...</option>
            <option value='01'>Jan</option>
            <option value='02'>Feb</option>
            <option value='03'>Mar</option>
            <option value='04'>Apr</option>
            <option value='05'>May</option>
            <option value='06'>June</option>
            <option value='07'>July</option>
            <option value='08'>Aug</option>
            <option value='09'>Sept</option>
            <option value='10'>Oct</option>
            <option value='11'>Nov</option>
            <option value='12'>Dec</option>
      </select>
     <select id="years">
       <?php
          for($yr=10; $yr<=$year; $yr++)
    {
        echo "<option value='".$yr."'>".$years[$yr]."</option>";
    }
   ?>
    </select>
  </div>
```

this is the start of my month.php

```
     <?php
      if (isset($_REQUEST['m'])) 
      {
      $m = $_REQUEST['m'];
     // $y = $_REQUEST['y'];
      include '../../include/dbconnect.php';

      ?>
```

Comment: i added the code from my month.php

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function that runs on change of either dropdown, and passes in both parameters at once:

```
$('#months, #years').change(function(event)
{
    var m=$('#months').val();
    var y=$('#years').val();

    // combine the conditions, so both must be valid before running
    if( (m!='00' || m!='NULL') &&
        (y!='10' || y!='NULL') )
    {
        $('#display').load('../crd_reports/month.php', {"y": y, "m": m});
                                     // notice additional param ^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Then in `month.php`, you can grab both parameters and use them to populate your report:

```
<?php
// 'y' also has to be given before we continue
if ( isset($_REQUEST['m']) && isset($_REQUEST['y']) ) 
{
    $m = $_REQUEST['m'];
    $y = $_REQUEST['y'];
    include '../../include/dbconnect.php';

    // do something with $m and $y
}
else
{
    echo 'Please provide month and year.';
}
?>
```

Comment: and then for the isset is have this one if(isset($_REQUEST['m'])) how should i do that?

Comment: I think you mean `var m=$("#months").val();var y=$("#years").val();`

Comment: is that so?i'm trying to get different values from the drop downs.

Comment: @shobe089: lol, they were talking to me about my code :)  Yes, you will want to do `$_REQUEST['m']` and `$_REQUEST['y']` to get the month and year as you did before.  Except, they will both be available at once now instead of one at a time.

Comment: so how am i going to get different values from the two forms and how could i make them available one a time?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
     $("#months").change(function(event)
    {
         var m=$(this).val();
         if( m == '00')
         { 
         }
         else if(m!='00' || m!='NULL')
         {
            $("#display").load('../crd_reports/month.php', {"m":m, "y": $("#years").val()});
         }

    });

    $("#years").change(function(event)
    {
         var y=$(this).val();
         if( y == '10')
         {
         }
         else if(y!='10' || y!='NULL')
         {
            $("#display").load('../crd_reports/month.php', {"y":y, "m": $("#months").val()});
         }
    });
  });
```

Comment: how would i get the value of m and y using isset? i'm using this one right now if(isset($_REQUEST['m']))

Comment: Use `$_POST['m']` for `m` and `$_POST['y']` for `y`.