# jQuery value to php dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i'm still asking the same question regarding my drop downs.i have these two drop downs that sets the month and year respectively. the first drop down would allow the user to choose a month.if user would not choose any of the options the display would be the current month.same with the year drop down.i have already done it with a single drop down but i can't do it for two drop downs.scenario would be user could use from the month and let the year drop down to be in default and vice versa.

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $("#months").change(function(event)
      {
         var m= $(this).val();
         if(m!='00' || m!='NULL')
         {
            $("#memcount").load('../crd_reports/month.php', {"m":m});
            $("#top10").load('../crd_reports/top10_monthly.php', {"m":m});

         }

    });

    $("#years").change(function(event)
    {
         var y=$(this).val();
         if( y == '10')
         {
         }
         else if(y!='10' || y!='NULL')
         {
            $("#display").load('../crd_reports/month.php', {"y":y});
            $("#top10").load('../crd_reports/top10_monthly.php', {"m":m});
         }
    });
});
```

this is my month.php. this file has the same content as the top10_monthly.php

```
     if (isset($_REQUEST['m'])) 
     {
       $m = $_REQUEST['m'];
       include '../../include/dbconnect.php';
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE admin_level LIKE 'CRD' ORDER BY id";
       $result =mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [get values of two drop down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019909/get-values-of-two-drop-down)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to set the date from the db to the page.Is it right?
If so , I think there is no need to do that , for you can just transfer the date value includes yeaer,month and day to the js by write php code in the js .
for example:

```
<script language="javascript">
   var y=<?php echo $d['year']?>;
   var m=<?php echo $d['month']?>;
   var d=<?php echo $d['day']?>;
</script>
```

the $d is an array from the db. then you can use the jquery set the value to the drop down in the front html . But attenstion you should put the code in the $(function(){}).

Comment: yes i am trying to set the dates to filter those from the data base.